# UITableView commitEditingStyle returns nil indexPath

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I have been working on UITableViews in iOS8. I'm using Non-ARC and In my code I have declared and i have set a delegate to it.

When

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

gets called, indexPath returns nil. I have dealloced my TableView in dealloc method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast found answer,actually i am calling commitEditingStyle manually.Where button added as subview to tablevewcell.In ios 7 if we call superview over buttonobject(i.e[buttonObj superview]) it returns UITableViewCellScrollView again we have to call superView for getting UITableviewCell i.e([[buttonObj superview]superview])

In IOS 8 UITableViewCellScrollView is deprecated that is we need to call only buttons superview (i.e just [buttonObj superview]) then it returns UITableViewCell.I think someone faced same problem

```
                        That's it problem Solved.
```